# How to use an interpolated string as a topic name for Firebase Cloud Functions and Typescript

Tags: ios, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, interpolation

I'm trying to write a cloud function that sends a notification to a topic. Currently I have the topic listed as an interpolated string like this:

```
"topic": `Group: ${groupID}`,
```

However, whenever the function is called, I get this error: `malformed topic name`

```
export const groupMessageReceived = functions.firestore
    .document("Groups/{groupID}/Chat/{message}").onCreate((create, context) => {
      const messageDoc = create.data();
      const groupID = context.params.groupID;
      console.log(`Group: ${groupID}`);
      // const topicName = "Group: " + groupID;
      // sending message to the person who is in the group
      const message = {
        "notification": {
          "title": groupID,
          "body": messageDoc.senderName + ": " + messageDoc.messageContent,
        },
        "topic": `Group: ${groupID}`,
      };

      admin.messaging().send(message)
          .then((response) => {
            // Response is a message ID string.
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
          });
    });
```

Does anybody have any suggestions for how to fix this? I can't seem to figure it out and can't find any posts. Thank you for any suggestions you have! If you need me to attach any more source code, let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the error, I think you need to double-check the topic name and make sure it's aligned with the requirements, described in the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics-legacy):

> Developers can choose any topic name that matches the regular
> expression: `"/topics/[a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]+"`.

Comment: Yes I think so, I tried what was suggested yesterday, but I’m still getting the same error. However, after running some print statements I realized that my variable sometimes came out as nil. So I’m going to try to retest with a defined variable, then I’ll mark this forum as resolved! thanks

Comment: This worked for me thanks! I had a space in there and forgot that those are not allowed. I also realized in the process that my variables were not being defined, which continued to cause the issue. Thanks for your help!